# Effective way to draw amCharts graphic with too many data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, amcharts

I have created a system described below:

There are some devices running with Linux. These devices send some info like load average amount, free memory amount, serial number, uptime to the database continuously (every 30 seconds). And then I fetch this data, show on webpage and create charts. It is a simple system. I used php for webpage, PDO for database operations, amCharts for charts. I drew charts for just free memory and load average data. But there is a problem with performance. I will explain the problem with an example. Let's take a look at free memory data:

Every 30 seconds devices send data to database. Assume that data is being sent for 7 days continuously. This means `(60 / 30) * 60 * 24 * 7 ~ 20000` rows have to be fetched from database to draw single device's free memory chart after 7 days. In every reload I had to fetch all 20000 rows all together. Because I have more than 10 devices, page reload takes too much time and performance is very low.

This is what chart looks like with 20000 rows:
[image: chart with 20000 rows]

What I am doing is:

Fetch all free memory data from database as an array in a lump in getchartdata.php

```
if (isset($_POST["SerialNumber"]) && isset($_POST["Type"])) {
    $serialNumber = $_POST["SerialNumber"];
    $type = $_POST["Type"];
    if ($type == "LoadAverage") {
        $loadavg =$crud->getLoadAvg($serialNumber);
        echo json_encode($loadavg);
    }
    elseif ($type == "Free") {
        $freemem =$crud->getFreeMem($serialNumber);
        echo json_encode($freemem);
    }
}
```

In index.php, I used ajax to get data from getchartdata.php to javascript. I used callback function to use data after get it. And then I fill each dive with charts.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".device").each(function() {
        //In index.php, I use other php functions to get serial numbers and fill divs with each device's serial number.
        serialNumber = $(this).text().trim();

        //I use local storage to keep "active" tab info. This way when I click the related div, it will get active and this code block will be executed.
        if (localStorage.getItem("active") == serialNumber) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $("#" + serialNumber).addClass("active");
            getChartInfo(serialNumber, "LoadAverage", createChart);
            getChartInfo(serialNumber, "Free", createChart);
        }
        else if (localStorage.getItem("active") == null || localStorage.getItem("active") == "" ) {
            $('.nav-tabs li:first').addClass('active');
            $('.tab-pane:first-child').addClass('active');
            serialNumber = $('.nav-tabs li:first').text().trim();
            getChartInfo(serialNumber, "LoadAverage", createChart);
            getChartInfo(serialNumber, "Free", createChart);
        }       
    }); 

     $(".device a").click(function() {
        getChartInfo($(this).text(), createChart);
        if ($(".device").hasClass('active')) {
            localStorage.setItem("active", $(this).text())
            $("#status-" + $(this).text()).addClass("active");
        }
    });

function getChartInfo(SerialNumber, Type) {   
    //Types: LoadAverage, Free

    var postData = 'SerialNumber='+SerialNumber+'&Type='+Type;
     divId = Type + "-" + SerialNumber

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'getchartdata.php',
        data:postData,
        success:function(ajaxResponse){
            ///console.log(ajaxResponse);
            createChart(ajaxResponse, Type, SerialNumber);
        },
        dataType:"json"
    });
}

function createChart(ajaxResponse, Type, SerialNumber) {
    //console.log(ajaxResponse);
    var chartData = [];

    for(var a in ajaxResponse) {
        date1 = new Date(a);

        chartData.push({
            date: date1,
            loadavg: ajaxResponse[a]
        });
    }
    console.log(chartData);
    console.log(divId+"-first");

    if (Type == "LoadAverage") {
        console.log("loadaverage");
        divId = Type + "-" + SerialNumber
        console.log(divId+"-load");
        var chart = AmCharts.makeChart(divId, {
            "type": "serial",
            "theme": "light",
            "marginRight": 80,
            "dataProvider": chartData,
            "valueAxes": [{
                "position": "left",
                "title": "Load Average"
            }],
            "graphs": [{
                "id": "g1",
                "fillAlphas": 0.4,
                "valueField": "loadavg",
                 "balloonText": "<div style='margin:5px; font-size:19px;'><b>[[value]]</b></div>"
            }],
            "chartScrollbar": {
                "graph": "g1",
                "scrollbarHeight": 80,
                "backgroundAlpha": 0,
                "selectedBackgroundAlpha": 0.1,
                "selectedBackgroundColor": "#888888",
                "graphFillAlpha": 0,
                "graphLineAlpha": 0.5,
                "selectedGraphFillAlpha": 0,
                "selectedGraphLineAlpha": 1,
                "autoGridCount": true,
                "color": "#AAAAAA"
            },
            "chartCursor": {
                "categoryBalloonDateFormat": "JJ:NN, DD MMMM",
                "cursorPosition": "mouse"
            },
            "categoryField": "date",
            "categoryAxis": {
                "minPeriod": "mm",
                "parseDates": true
            },
            "export": {
                "enabled": true,
                 "dateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS"
            }
        });
    chart.addListener("dataUpdated", zoomChart);
    chart.zoomToIndexes(chartData.length - 1000, chartData.length);

    }

    if (Type == "Free") {
        console.log("free");
        divId = Type + "-" + SerialNumber
        console.log(divId+"-free")
        var chart1 = AmCharts.makeChart(divId, {
            "type": "serial",
            "theme": "light",
            "marginRight": 80,
            "dataProvider": chartData,
            "valueAxes": [{
                "position": "left",
                "title": "Free Memory"
            }],
            "graphs": [{
                "id": "g1",
                "fillAlphas": 0.4,
                "valueField": "loadavg",
                 "balloonText": "<div style='margin:5px; font-size:19px;'><b>[[value]]</b></div>"
            }],
            "chartScrollbar": {
                "graph": "g1",
                "scrollbarHeight": 80,
                "backgroundAlpha": 0,
                "selectedBackgroundAlpha": 0.1,
                "selectedBackgroundColor": "#888888",
                "graphFillAlpha": 0,
                "graphLineAlpha": 0.5,
                "selectedGraphFillAlpha": 0,
                "selectedGraphLineAlpha": 1,
                "autoGridCount": true,
                "color": "#AAAAAA"
            },
            "chartCursor": {
                "categoryBalloonDateFormat": "JJ:NN, DD MMMM",
                "cursorPosition": "mouse"
            },
            "categoryField": "date",
            "categoryAxis": {
                "minPeriod": "mm",
                "parseDates": true
            },
            "export": {
                "enabled": true,
                 "dateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS"
            }
        });

    chart1.addListener("dataUpdated", zoomChart);
    chart1.zoomToIndexes(chartData.length - 1000, chartData.length);

    }
    // when we apply theme, the dataUpdated event is fired even before we add listener, so
    // we need to call zoomChart here
    zoomChart();
    // this method is called when chart is first inited as we listen for "dataUpdated" event
    function zoomChart() {
        // different zoom methods can be used - zoomToIndexes, zoomToDates, zoomToCategoryValues
    }
}
```

What can I do to draw charts effectively with this so many and continuously increased data? There may be parts that I missed to explain. Please ask me and I can explain further.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For large, date-based datasets, you're better off using the Stock Chart from AmCharts. It's better designed for that use case with it's data grouping functionality, which improves performance by minimizing the amount of points being displayed. The serial charts in the regular AmCharts JavaScript Library can only handle very small fraction of that number of data points.

As for loading multiple charts at once, a couple of techniques we typically recommend are lazy-loading each chart when they're scrolled into view or daisy-chaining the initialization/update. A more complete explanation of these techniques can be found [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44494885/6106614).

Comment: Thanks. It seems Stock Chart is what I need in this case. I'll try to use Stock Chart and daisy-chaining initialization and come back with the results.

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you direct answer for that. But while I cannot add a comment because of my current reputation, I will give 2 suggestion here:

1. If you don't have to get all these 20.000 records at once, you can simplify your chart or create one more simplified amChart that only shows for example 1000 records.
2. If you HAVE TO get all of these record to your amChart, I can recommend you to use "asynchronous" record fetching. This way you can split your "one" database query into various asynchronous queries.

And as @xorspark mentioned, you can divide your chart into multiple chart and can use lazy loading.

But I recommend you to merge multiple chart with lazy loading and asynchronous record fetching.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of basic optimizations that can be made to rendering, while still using your current structure:

1. pre-format dates (i.e.convert from date time property to the format that you wish to use, as the chart does this automatically on all your data)
2. group axis data, as this will reduce strain on the rendering.  This code groups all data and only draws once for every 24 entries (and draw finer detail as you zoom in):

   ```
   var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
        dateAxis.baseInterval = {
                       "timeUnit": "hour",
                       "count": 1
                   };
                   dateAxis.groupData = true;
                   dateAxis.groupCount = 24;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when I had to load more than 3000 records into a bar chart. Naturally, the initial load time was too much and impacted UX. To solve this I added scrollbar and implemented lazy loading based on the scroll position.

```
// init chart and add scrollbar
chart.scrollbarX.events.on('rangechanged', () => {
if (e.target.end === 1 && !isLast) {
        fetchData({ dataId, nextPageToken })
        .then((data) => {
           chartRef.current.activityChart.bindData(trends);
        })
 }
});
```